# turn off sound only - how?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, volume

I have this problem:

How do you turn off the sound in a game only? I ask because I have two buttons in my settings: turn music on/off and sound on/off. turning music on and off is really easy because it uses a specific sound channel. But How do you turn off the volume the sound only (e.g. music is still playing but not the sound of the game)?

When I mute the sound via SoundMixer.soundtransform you can't hear anything so that's not what I wanted to have. In my game all sounds are thrown into an array. My first idea was that I go through all sounds listed in the array and turn off the volume but that's not working. Please - can anyone help? Thank you very much.

```
//not working

private var sounds:Array;
private var soundChannels:Array = [];
private var muteSoundTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

public function muteSoundOnly():void {

muteSoundTransform.volume = 0;

var soundLength:int = soundChannels.length - 1;
for (var soundCtr:int = soundLength; soundCtr >= 0; soundCtr--)
{

soundChannels[soundCtr].soundTransform = muteSoundTransform;

}

}
```

Comment: Adding the sounds to an array is a good solution. Are you sure you are not adding the music to the same Array? Or that the music uses the same transform as the effects.

Comment: Is your mute function getting called only once? Or did you just leave out the code that toggles the mute unmute calls? In which case you could just have one function, toggleSoundOnly() that toggles the sound.

Comment: The music uses a different soundChannel (called SoundTrackChannel) so this should be not the problem. Yes, I think the function gets called once only. My initial thought was that you set the volume once. So do I have to loop this function?

Comment: Ok. I got the problem solved.:) Actually I just forgot to insert a public variable for my sound events so I can control the volume. I'm such a dumbass!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to do it like this:

```
var soundsON = true;
```

and then before you play any sound effects, make sure sounds are ON, like so:

```
if (soundsON) {
 mySound.play();
}
```

If you make your mute button do `soundsON = false;`, your sound effects won't be played.

Comment: You don't handle the case when a sound is playing and you press the mute button.